# Powershell Run Bat File in Remote machine

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I modified a function I got from Microsoft forum, it purpose is to run copy a bat file to a remote machine and to run it there. I could see the file being copied over, however it seems not working when I try to call the Invoke-Command to execute the file. Any advice will be appreciated, thank you :)

```
function Run-BatchFile ($computer, [string]$batLocation)
{

    $sessions = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computer -Credential qa\qalab3
    Copy-Item -Path $batLocation -Destination "\\$computer\C$\MD5temp" #copy the file locally on the machine where it will be executed
    $batfilename = Split-Path -Path $batLocation -Leaf
    Invoke-Command -Session $sessions -ScriptBlock {param($batfilename) "cmd.exe /c C:\MD5temp\$batfilename" } -ArgumentList $batfilename -AsJob
     $remotejob | Wait-Job #wait for the remote job to complete     
    Remove-Item -Path "\\$computer\C$\MD5temp\$batfilename" -Force #remove the batch file from the remote machine once job done
    Remove-PSSession -Session $sessions #remove the PSSession once it is done
}

Run-BatchFile 192.168.2.207 "D:\MD5Check\test.bat"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You put the commandline you're trying to run in quotes.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $sessions -ScriptBlock {
  param($batfilename)
  "cmd.exe /c C:\MD5temp\$batfilename"
} -ArgumentList $batfilename -AsJob
```

PowerShell will just echo bare strings, not interpret them as command and execute them. You need to use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849893.aspx) for the latter:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $sessions -ScriptBlock {
  param($batfilename)
  Invoke-Expression "cmd.exe /c C:\MD5temp\$batfilename"
} -ArgumentList $batfilename -AsJob
```

or (better) remove the quotes and (optionally) use the call operator:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $sessions -ScriptBlock {
  param($batfilename)
  & cmd.exe /c "C:\MD5temp\$batfilename"
} -ArgumentList $batfilename -AsJob
```